# PHP Proxy php.ini setting

Tags: proxy, php

I'm trying to set get PHP running properly in a `chroot` jail on OSX. Because DNS lookups don't work in a chroot on OSX I would like to set all TCP connections to go through a proxy on 127.0.0.1

There is a bug report where this option was allegedly [added to PHP 5](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=29280)

> Summary: Add php.ini option to set default proxy for wrappers

However I don't seem able to find out what this option is. How do you set the default proxy for all stream wrappers?